# SQL - Get results only results from table 1, where all rows on table 2 meet condition true

Tags: sql-server-2014

Ok, so this seems like an easy one but it's got me stumped and I can't find what I'm looking for around the net.
It probably is really simple and I've just had a long day and can't get it to work.

I have 2 tables: variant_detail, variant_setting 

Sample data:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| variant_detail.vad_pd_id | variant_detail.vad_id | 
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| 3                        | 3                     |
| 18                       | 25                    |
| 3                        | 69                    |
| 5789                     | 8954                  |
| 89                       | 254                   |
| 1880                     | 6987                  |
| 246                      | 879                   |
| 5789                     | 774                   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+

+----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| variant_setting.vas_vad_id | variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product |
+----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| 3                          | TRUE                                     |
| 25                         | TRUE                                     |
| 69                         | FALSE                                    |
| 8954                       | TRUE                                     |
| 254                        | FALSE                                    |
| 6987                       | FALSE                                    |
| 879                        | FALSE                                    |
| 774                        | TRUE                                     |
+----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

What I'm trying to get is only rows vad_pd_id where variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product = TRUE.

This is not a standard join as not all variants will be discontinued.  I've tried Distinct and all sorts!
E.g. There would be no entry for vad_pd_id = 3 as one row is TRUE and one is FALSE 
However, there would be an entry for vad_pd_id = 5789 as both rows are TRUE 
Here's the code I had a shot with:
 `Select distinct vad_pd_id
From variant_detail Inner Join
  variant_setting On variant_detail.vad_id = variant_setting.vas_vad_id where variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product = TRUE`
 
 
Look forward to some assistance from all the techs please!

**EDIT**

I now need to update a separate table: product_analysis.  Field is pa_pd_id 
So code something like
`update update product_analysis
set product_analysis.pa_l_9 =1
*using the select function just created`

Comment: It shouldn't be returning `3` as only one of the lines in variant_setting is TRUE?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed `all rows` part of the title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `bool_and` aggregate function ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html)).

> true if all input values are true, otherwise false

You need to aggregate the `vas_discontinued_product` values and use `bool_and()`. So remove `WHERE` clause:

`where variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product = TRUE`

and add:

```
GROUP BY vad_pd_id
HAVING bool_and(variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product)
```

And you don't have to add `= TRUE` for boolean conditions.

---

**EDIT**

As it turns out that this is no PostgreSQL you can not use `bool_and`. But there is an alternative method that should work with (I hope) all SQL *flavors*:

Cast `boolean` to `int` and use `min` aggregate function. `FALSE::int = 0` and `TRUE::int = 1`, so if `min` returns `1` that means **all** values are `TRUE`.

```
GROUP BY vad_pd_id
HAVING min(CAST(variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product AS integer)) = 1
```

Comment: Hello @Adam  Thanks for the reply.  However I've mixed up the SQL types (based on what my client told me), my apologies.  They're not using postgres, It's MS SQL Server and bool_and therefore doesn't work.  Can you assist further?<br/>  I've also changed the tags.

Comment: Thanks Adam <br/>  Your conversion to int didn't work for me, but I used the CAST method and that works great.  Thanks for all your help <br/> 
`Select distinct vad_pd_id
From variant_detail Inner Join
  variant_setting On variant_detail.vad_id = variant_setting.vas_vad_id
GROUP BY vad_pd_id
HAVING min(CAST(variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product as integer)) = 1`

Comment: I've now got a further question!  - how do I update a completely separate table?  I've added it to the main question

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `CAST`, thanx for pointing that. As to your second question: it should be asked in a new post, but I can give you a hint: `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id IN (SELECT id ...);`.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks Adam for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`select vad_pd_id 
from variant_detail 
inner join variant_setting 
on variant_detail.vad_id = variant_setting.vas_vad_id 
group by vad_pd_id 
having bool_and(vas_discontinued_product) is true`

it will return values 5789 and 18 - which are the only ones having all TRUEs...